# set the edge long as label

Tags: graphviz, dot

I try to draw a FSM by graphviz 2.38.

Here are some questions:

1. How to set the edge length same as its' label?
2. How to set the edge as rectangle edges?
3. How to set the labels will not overlap the edges?

   ```
   digraph test {
       rankdir=LR;
       n1 -> n2 
       n2 -> n2 [label="00000000000000"]
       n2 -> n2 [label="11111111111111"]
       n2 -> n2 [label="22222222222222"]
       n2 -> n2 [label="33333333333333"]
   }
   ```

What I get Now:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you post a picture of how you want to have it look like in the end. I understand your words but cannot translate it into something visual.

Comment: @vaettchen I update the question, thanks!

Comment: Possible to use invisible nodes `node[ shape = point, width = 0 ];` and edges of a certain minlen but I'm afraid I would not know a generic solution.